# Android set diffrent value to selected item in spinner with items shown in the spinner pop up

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter

I have list of countries and their pre phone codes in hashMap like this:

```
hashmap.put("Angola", "+244");
```

I want to set the array of my country names to spinner adapter, and when the user clicked on spinner to select one country show her/him the list of country names, but when he/she select one country in spinner text shoe the country code.
I don't know how to do this.
the images may help understand what I mean:
[image: in pop up selection of spinner]
[image: The shown in spinner]

Comment: So you want to set a TextView with the Country code value of a selected Spinner ?

Comment: good suggestion  in form of question :)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to very similar to how you're accessing the names. Unfortunately, maps are not indexed by position, so you have to iterate over the entries, keys, or values. `LinkedHashMap` can be useful here. Here is a simple test case:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class Test {
    // NOTE: Using `LinkedHashMap` here to ensure that
    // the entries will be ordered by insertion.
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        map.put("Country1", "+123");
        map.put("Country2", "+456");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("+123", getValueForPosition(0));
        assertEquals("+456", getValueForPosition(1));
    }

    private String getValueForPosition(int position) {
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : map.values()) {
            if (i == position) {
                return s;
            }
            i += 1;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```